# Wrap tor socks proxy with http proxy in command line

Tags: proxy, tor, socks

I have installed `tor` via `apt` and it is listening on port number 9050

```
# netstat -ntlup | grep tor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13566/tor
```

Since tor is a socks proxy and I want to use that an http proxy, I installed `polipo` via `apt` and configured that as below

```
# cat /etc/polipo/config 
logSyslog = true
logFile = /var/log/polipo/polipo.log
allowedClients = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.0/24 # Expose your network (modify accordingly)
socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"
socksProxyType = socks5
proxyAddress = "0.0.0.0"    # IPv4 only
```

Then I restarted `tor` and `polipo` services. The `polipo` log says it is listening on port number 8123 which sounds odd!!!

I know I have to set the variables for `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. So,

```
# export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:9050 https_proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
```

However, the `wget` command is unable to reach the site with the following error

```
 # wget https://torproject.org
 --2018-03-29 21:14:28--  https://torproject.org/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9050... connected.
Proxy tunneling failed: Tor is not an HTTP ProxyUnable to establish SSL connection.
```

What is wrong with the config? I need to find a way for `wget` to use that in a bash script.

[1] https://www.marcus-povey.co.uk/2016/03/24/using-tor-as-a-http-proxy/

Comment: For those reading this, please note that [polipo](https://www.irif.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change:

```
export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:9050 https_proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
```

to

```
export http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8123 https_proxy=127.0.0.1:8123
```

You set the proxy environment variables to Tor's SOCKS proxy, not the polipo HTTP proxy.

If you installed Tor from `apt`, you could also try:

```
torify wget https://torproject.org
```

This will force whatever program you run through it to use Tor's SOCKS proxy.

Or, just use curl which has built in SOCKS support:

```
curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 https://torproject.org/
```